# git clone error fatal: deflateInit2: stream consistency error (no message)

Tags: linux, git

I just installed `git` on RHEL 3 via source code.
It's up and running, but I get the following error when I tried to clone a repository:

> fatal: deflateInit2: stream consistency error (no message) fatal: The
>   remote end hung up unexpectedly

I was wondering if I need some special network config because the repository resides in Europe and I am in Asia. we are on the same CORP network though.

Comment: Are you cloning using http url ? If so, then it does not matter. You only need internet access.

Comment: Hi @RajeshKaushik you are right, it is via http:// but I am behind a corp firewall and the Git repo is also within the network. Why do I need internet access for this?

Comment: @RajeshKaushik inwas thinking this is related to the zlib version of RHEL3? Maybe I need to upgrade it or something?

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue to be related to the RHEL3 Zlib dependency of Git.
When I updated Zlib, this issue was resolved.